# Is there a way to create a custom connector for other tenant?

Tags: azure-api-management, powerapps, power-automate-custom-connector

I am looking for Is there a way to create a custom connector for other tenants or as guests?

[image]

Comment: is there a reason why I got the -1 on the question ?

Answer (score 0):

A connector is a wrapper or a proxy around an API that interact between Power Automate or Power Apps and the back-end service or data source.

[image: Connector]

The custom connector (API connector) enables you to connect your own web API (REST API) in Power Automate and Power Apps. **To create a custom connector first we need to enable authentication in Azure Active Directory then register one of the APIs as a custom connector and lastly connect to it in Power Automate.**

#### Authentication in Azure Active Directory

First, you need to create an Azure Active Directory (AAD) application that performs the authentication when calling the API endpoint.

- First create an **App registration** in Azure Active Directory.
- Now in the **settings** of the registered App, go to **required permission** and **Add API**.

For more detailed information check this [Enable authentication in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/azure-active-directory-authentication#enable-authentication-in-azure-active-directory) section of the Microsoft document.

#### Custom connector

After configuring the AAD Application we can now create the custom connector.

- After clicking the **Settings** at the top of Power Automate web page, select **custom connector**.
- Select **Create custom connector**, then **Import an OpenAPI file** .
- In **Security** page, provide AAD information for the application and set Resource URL.

For detailed information check this [Create a custom connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/azure-active-directory-authentication#create-a-custom-connector) section of the Microsoft document.